# What is the default value of bias_filler type "constant" in Caffe's convolution layer?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, caffe

In the example layer below, what is the default value of bias_filler type "constant" in Caffe's convolution layer?

```
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 12
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
```

I can't find the answer in the documentation at http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers/convolution.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of documentation/information in [`caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto) file. This file describe the syntax of caffe's prototxt/binaryproto.

Looking for the proto definition of constant filler ([line 46](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto)):

> ```
> optional float value = 2 [default = 0]; // the value in constant filler
> ```

You can see the default value is 0.